# Topic removal policy seems way too unfair

Tags: feature-request

I'm not trying to be mean or disrespectful, but I recently submitted a couple questions, basically the same question just reworded because they were considered **"too broad"**.  If I had asked **"how to tell if someone pings me"**, that would be too broad I agree, but I asked **"With Delphi and Indy 10.6, I need to trigger an event when someone pings"**.

My question was specific for a programming language, using a specific communication module, seeking a specific event trigger; this is not broad in any sense of the word, and Remmy even gave me the answer I needed before it got removed thankfully, but others may need this information and it is a big disservice for just one person to do this because they do not understand the nature of the situation.

It seems like there should be safe guards, requiring 3 or more votes to remove a topic before the topic can be removed. Just something to consider.

I just get the impression that some people, who have been on Stack Exchange for a long time, may have forgotten what it's like to be fairly new to a topic and the complete frustration of not being able to find the answers because someone else asked questions in the past and they got removed like some of mine have; we can't learn and become better if people **"censor"** the questions of others.

Comment: it already takes *5* close votes to close a question. If your question was closed by a single person then that was a moderator or staff

Comment: Closing a question because the community feels its not a good topic, isn't censoring somebody, because that close question can be modified and improved then reopened at any point in time. "t seems like there should be safe guards, requiring 3 or more votes to remove a topic before the topic can be removed. " - There actually is.  If your question is being deleted it is because not only did multiple (more then 3) people vote to delete the question but also a moderator agreeed with those people.

Comment: If you want some feedback on your specific questions here, links to them could help (up to you). Also, fwiw, and *I don't know what this means here*, but I'm familiar with Remy from old days on Borland's QC portal and he has a special gift for constructing solid Delphi/Indy/RAD Studio answers to even the broadest and most incomprehensible of questions. In any case, learn from the experience. It's no big deal to have a question closed or put on hold. Ask how to improve it, [edit and] vote to reopen, or just move on, but don't dwell on it or rant, that is only counterproductive.

Comment: Wow, those Indy questions look off topic at first glance.  Meta peeps--check the tag before effecting.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, though it looks like just 1 person closed it, so I'm assuming it was a moderator, otherwise it seems like several people should have been listed as closing it; though it still seems bad, I'm sure other nubs have sought an answer to this type of question, yet we'll never know because they probably got the same treatment.  I did try rewording the question topic to be more specific, according to the bubble help, but the same person just removed it again.

Comment: Maybe, if something is removed for being "off topic" or "too broad", perhaps someone could give some specific help to form the question instead of just pointing to a help page that can seem pretty generalized; this way we can more easily learn how to pose our questions instead of spinning our wheels in frustration :\

Answer (score 13):

The folks who closed your questions tried to provide you with guidance in the comments. Remy in particular went to some effort to outline the *multiple* steps you'll have to take to accomplish what you want.

**This is your roadmap to asking better questions.** Focus on each step, describe what you know and where you're stuck, and provide the overall goal of your project only as context - then it becomes possible for folks to write answers that address the specific problems you face.

Comment: Yes, Remmy was (and has been) very helpful, though I was looking, as I stated, to see if it was possible, and I couldn't narrow it down any more than I did, having only some basic criteria and a feasibility question; found out it really wasn't feasible, but I think it should have been left up for the next poor guy that's wondering the same thing :/